# Shader to render objects with distance independent size

Tags: opengl, glsl, three.js, vertex-shader

I am trying to find a way to render certain objects in my 3d scene without the effects of the perspective projection. E.g. I want them to have the same pixel dimension independent of distance to the camera or the dimensions of the viewport.

Here is what I tried in the vertex shader so far

```
uniform vec2 screen_size;

varying float camera_distance;

void main() {
    mat4 mvp = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix;

    float scaleFactor = 2.0 * 50.0 / screen_size.x;
    float w = (mvp * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)).w;
    w = w * scaleFactor;

    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position.xyz * w, 1.0);
}
```

So far no luck.

Comment: Can't you just render them with an orthographic projection matrix?

Comment: @StefanAgartsson I thought about that too, but I am not sure if I achieve the desired effect: I have a 3d starmap and want to display a ring around some of the to display information. If I mix a 3d and an orthographic camera will the star and ring still line up?

Comment: For that case, it sounds like it would be simpler to scale your more distant rings using their transforms, rather than writing a new shader.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the shader code:

```
void main() {

mat4 mvp = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix;

vec4 temp = mvp * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);

gl_Position = vec4(temp.xy*w,temp.zw);
}
```

To adjust the size of the ring just change the size of the quad or triangle.